# How to sort null bin items at last in netsuite advanced pdf template?

Tags: netsuite, freemarker, suitescript

I created a Picklist using Advanced PDF in NetSuite. I want the items to be sorted out based on the BIN Number. Now items with blank bin number are coming first. Is there a way to sort the items last who has blank bin number?